# Keep arguments of a function unevaluated after replacement rules

Tags: functions, replacement

Consider an expression of type

```
f[a,b]+a+b
```

and a set of replacement rules

```
sub={a->1,b->2}
```

If I evaluate now the expression

```
f[a,b]+a+b/.sub
```

the output will be

```
3+f[1,2]
```

However, I need that the arguments of f are left unevaluated after the replacement rules are applied. In particular, I need my output to be

```
3+f[a,b]
```

I tried with **HoldAllComplete** and similars as attributes to **f**, but this seems not to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your rule slightly to reflect the fact that you want to leave the `f` expression unchanged:

```
f[a, b] + a + b /. {expr : f[__] :> expr, a -> 1, b -> 2}
```

> 3 + f[a, b]